# Unity not importing all actions from Blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm doing all my asset creation in Blender 2.69 and implementing in Unity 4.2. My object has about 8-10 actions, all with Fake users to prevent deletion. I've worked with both .blend files and .fbx files that were exported from Blender. When I import either a .blend or a .fbx file into Unity, and I go to animation options in the import options tab, I am only seeing five clips show up (even in the .fbx, despite selecting "All Actions" during export.)

I went through a few hoops. I made each action a separate file with the object@clip.fbx filename format. I also did each action as a separate file with the actions baked. In both of those solutions, I had deformation errors.

I want to be able to use all my actions straight from my .blend file if possible. Why don't they show up?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I believe you're supposed to bake the animations before they show up in Unity.  And make sure that the checkbox in the Export FBX property sheet for Baked Animations is checked.